# Phone disassembly: what's that part for?

Tags: repair, telephone

I replaced a broken screen for a [Moto G (1st generation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moto_G_%281st_generation%29), and now I'm struggling with 'ghost inputs/ghost touches'. In order to track down the problem, I came across a part which is located between the backside of the screen and the 'mainboard' of the phone (see image attached). What is this part required for?

[image: Part]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a shield. It absorbs EM radiation by draining it to the electrical ground of the phone. They are used in order to meet emission specifications created by the FCC or similar authorities, or to prevent EM radiation from interfering with other parts of the device.

Comment: So better leave it in?

Comment: You almost always want to leave it in place, yes.

Comment: And if slightly misplaced it can fail to make good contact, which may cause glitches

Comment: It might also be affecting antenna radiation pattern as well and impedance as well.

Comment: That sounds *exactly* like something that would cause "ghost touches".